# Error: resizing partition e2fsck failed with exit code 1 - Android Studio

Tags: android

I am new to android development and installed android studio with 5.1 Lollipop version (api 22). When i run my application in emulator i got following error. Please view error screenshot below. Please anyone guide what i am missing in my android studio installation or while creating project. Thanks in advance.

[image: Error Screeshot]

Answer (score 0):

Ultra beginner here but I uninstalled Android studio, reinstalled the JDK and JRE in C:\Java.  Apparently Java wasn't installed properly and was able to test it by opening the command prompt and verifying by typing "java -version" to get it to spit out the correct version I installed.  Hope this helps!